# Why are validation errors not working as expected inside ListBox and ListBoxItem?

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, listbox

I've been trying to implement some error validation in a WPF application, and I've been banging my head for two days on how to do it correctly inside a ListBox. I'm using ObservableValidator and property attributes from the CommunityToolkit, that part appears to work fine.

To give a little more context, I have a ListBox containing items that can each be edited with several TextBoxes, ComboBoxes and so forth. I am validating things like required fields, an Ip address, fairly standard stuff. My issue is that when one of these fields has an error, on top of it having a red border, the same thing goes for another unrelated control. I've searched a lot on this subject and I can't understand why another control in the same grid is changing too.

[image: An example with the name being empty]

The ListBox thing seems to be normal at least, I've reproduced it with a very simple example and I've finally understood that the ListBox is in error state if one of the selected item's properties isn't valid. It can be deactivated by putting an empty error template on the ListBox so I'm fine with it.

On the other hand, I have absolutely no clue as to why some other controls inside the item grid are in error state too, and I can't reproduce it in my simple example. I also can't reasonably share all the code needed to make that whole view work but I'll try to give the most pertinent bits below. Also please note that I didn't write the whole code and want to change the least possible amount.

The content of the main view:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent" Margin="10" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Sources}" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSource}"
             ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource SourceListBoxItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
<Grid>
```

The corresponding view model :

```
public partial class SourcesViewModel : ObservableObject, IMenuItemViewModel
{
    private readonly IDialogService dialogService;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private SourceItem selectedSource = new();

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<SourceItem> sources;

    public SourcesViewModel(IDialogService dialogServiceParam)
    {
        dialogService = dialogServiceParam;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void ShowColorIconDialog()
    {
        ColorIcon colorIcon = new(SelectedSource.Icon, SelectedSource.Color);

        dialogService.ShowDialog<ColorIconSelectionViewModel>(colorIcon);
    }
}
```

The SourceItem definition:

```
public partial class SourceItem : ObservableValidator, ICloneable
{
    public SourceItem() { }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int id;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    private string name;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string color;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Icon is required")]
    private string icon;
}
```

The style for the ListBox items:

```
<Style x:Key="SourceListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <customControls:CustomExpander x:Name="Expander"
                    Width="650"
                    Template="{DynamicResource ExpanderTemplate}"
                    IsExpanded="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                    TitlePart1="{lex:Loc Label_Sources_SourceHeader}"
                    TitlePart2="{Binding Id, StringFormat={}{0} :}"
                    TitlePart3="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="10,2">
                </customControls:CustomExpander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The data template for the expander content:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderContentTemplate" xmlns:enum="clr-namespace:Medinbox.RoomManager.Models.Enums">
        <Grid Background="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,5">
               <TextBlock Text="{lex:Loc Label_Sources_SourceName}"/>
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}">
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                 <userControls:SourceIconColorButton BackgroundColor="{Binding DataContext.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem }}"
                                                            IconName="{Binding DataContext.Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                                                            DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType= ListBoxItem}}"
                                                            Command ="{Binding DataContext.ShowColorIconDialogCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have simplified it a lot by removing panel and controls to get at the heart of the issue: when the Name TextBox is invalid, the ColorIcon custom control had a red border too, as shown above. I would maybe understand if it was the case for all the controls but it's just this one.

I'll really welcome any idea at this point, as well as explanations about how this is all supposed to work.

EDIT : I've added more code (should have shared the view models right away) and tried to be clearer on some parts, I hope it helps.

Comment: Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my question? I guess it's not the lack of research, so if you think it's unclear, not useful, it lacks code, I'd be happy to provide more info because I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end it was very confusing because of how ListBox handles validation, and I should have seen the real issue earlier.

It was in that part:

```
<userControls:SourceIconColorButton BackgroundColor="{Binding DataContext.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem }}"
                                                            IconName="{Binding DataContext.Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                                                            DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType= ListBoxItem}}"
                                                            Command ="{Binding DataContext.ShowColorIconDialogCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

The control shouldn't have been bound to the whole SourceItem object on top of its color in icon. When the name or the IP address of the SourceItem was invalid, the object itself has `HasErrors` being true, so the custom control had the red border too. I removed that binding that was probably a leftover and it works.

Another control had a SourceItem as a `CommandParameter` and I couldn't change it that easily, so I used `ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False` on this binding as it seemed to be the right solution in this case.